# Function to automatically identify valid JSON object(s) contained in a string?

Tags: r, regex, tidyverse, stringr, jsonlite

Suppose we have one or more valid JSON object(s) inside a string. Consider the string:

```
paste0("klsdjfo234u", toJSON(iris[1, ]), "lsdkfj20934ujsdfl")

# [1] "klsdjfo234u[{\"Sepal.Length\":5.1,\"Sepal.Width\":3.5,\"Petal.Length\":1.4,\"Petal.Width\":0.2,\"Species\":\"setosa\"}]lsdkfj20934ujsdfl"
```

If we know where the JSON is in the string, we can easily extract it with `str_split()` or `substr()`

But for very long strings this could be laborious and manual.

Is there any function that *automatically* finds valid JSON from within a string? (without manual intervention)

#### Example with desired output

A function `find_JSON()` that receives a string, and returns valid JSON objects

```
paste0("klsdjfo234u", toJSON(iris[1, ]), "lsdkfj20934ujsdfl") %>% 
  find_JSON()
# [1] [{\"Sepal.Length\":5.1,\"Sepal.Width\":3.5,\"Petal.Length\":1.4,\"Petal.Width\":0.2,\"Species\":\"setosa\"}]
```

And

```
paste0("klsdjfo234u", toJSON(iris[1, ]), "lsdkfj20934ujsdfl") %>% 
  find_JSON %>% 
  jsonlite::fromJSON

#   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
#            5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might not be a full-proof method but how about we create a pattern to find json and extract it

```
vals <- paste0("klsdjfo234u", toJSON(iris[1, ]), "lsdkfj20934ujsdfl")

lapply(stringr::str_extract_all(vals, '\\[\\{.*\\}\\]'), jsonlite::fromJSON)

#[[1]]
#  Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
#1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa
```